# Delayed Job worker on Heroku tries to connect read-only follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, delayed-job, readonly

Here is the actual error from logfile:

```
2013-02-20T20:56:03+00:00 app[worker.1]:   SQL (11.1ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_by = null, locked_at = null WHERE (locked_by = 'host:05c659a5-86fd-46dd-b139-263e49a96171 pid:2')
2013-02-20T20:56:03+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2013-02-20T20:56:03+00:00 app[worker.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
2013-02-20T20:56:03+00:00 app[worker.1]: : UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2013-02-20 20:56:02.982379', locked_by = 'host:05c659a5-86fd-46dd-b139-263e49a96171 pid:2' WHERE id IN (SELECT  id FROM "delayed_jobs"  WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-02-20 20:56:02.882553' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-02-20 16:56:02.882574') OR locked_by = 'host:05c659a5-86fd-46dd-b139-263e49a96171 pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

This error also appears in the followers log. That's why assumed there is a problem with that. Delayed Job version: 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

It seems that issue came with recent update. See this Github issue for details:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/issues/34

For me downgrading to 0.3.3 worked.